# How do I insert into a column and after some time change myself automatically

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I would like to know how, after entering a "client", it appears in the column ("status") as "Contacted" and after 15 days it automatically changes to "Uncontacted".

I do not succeed .. I tried with 'select' between column "date time" and "status" but .. it does not show me anything .. and ..

Originally I need to insert .. it has to change automatically after those 15 days .. but I can not succeed..

Comment: Step 1 - write and test the appropriate query.  Step 2 - Schedule it to run every day.

Comment: you will need two columns, 1 - status and 2 - update date, create a job in your database to run every day, executing a query that will update the status when the update date is less than X days

Answer (score 0):

You could implement in C# by running scheduled job to find stale clients, and set status to "Uncontacted". e.g.

```
var staleClients = Clients.Where(x=> x.DateCreated.AddDays(15) < DateTime.UtcNow);
staleClients.Status = "Uncontacted";
dbContext.Save();
```

Hangfire is one possible option for running scheduled tasks.

Otherwise, a scheduled job in the database could perform the same functionality as above. e.g.

```
update Clients
set status = 'Uncontacted'
where DateCreated < dateadd(day, -15, getdate()) and status <> 'Uncontacted'
```